# text highlights only for a fraction of a seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, highlight, movieclip

Ok - this is hopefully my last post about flash:

I'm trying to highlight text in a scrollpane.
now I've tried highlighting it without a scrollpane, but the problem is the same, the text gets highlighted for a fraction of a second and then just goes back to normal.

I'm using the greensock LoaderMax library to load an external swf into the scrollpane.

I'm trying to keep things short, but here's how it works:

**EDIT: FULL & CURRENT SRC**

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;


//import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
// javascript call
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.text.TextField;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.containers.ScrollPane;
import fl.events.ScrollEvent;

//important for scrollpane events
import flash.events.Event;

import flash.text.TextSnapshot;

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite;
//cursors n' shit
import flash.ui.Mouse;

//debugging
import flash.utils.describeType;

import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain; 
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

import flash.display.LoaderInfo;

//timer
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.*;
/*
importing libraries:
Edit > Preferences > ActionScript > ActionScript 3.0 Settings > Source path
make sure to set path to parent of com folder or whatever

*/
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.loading.*;
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
import com.greensock.loading.display.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;





/*
In order to use the line this.addChild(border) your class has to be a display container. movieclip and sprite are the most common to use.
dont forget renaming the class here!
*/
public class expViewer10 extends MovieClip {

     var mc2:MovieClip;

     var nextPageButton:SimpleButton;
     var prevPageButton:SimpleButton;
     var jsButton:SimpleButton
     var searchButton:SimpleButton;


    var firstX:int = 0;
    var firstY:int = 0;
    var touchDown:Boolean = false;
    var startPos:int = 0;
    var textPos:int = 0; // aka endPos
    var oldStartPos:int = 0;
    var oldTextPos:int = 0; // aka endPos
    var currentlySelecting:Boolean = false;
    var currentText:String = "";
    var newSelection:Boolean = false;
    var snapshotTrigger:Boolean = false;

    // colors
    var preSelectionColor:Number = 0xDDAB00;
    var selectionColor:Number = 0xFFEF00;

     // array of arrays with [0] one selection
    //          [0][0] id [0][1] startPos ...[2] endPos [3] text
    var selectionsArray:Array = new Array();


    var theRectangle:DisplayObject;
    var markCounter:TextField;

    //mcScrollBar.setScrollProperties(1, 1, 4 );

    // need to be outside of function
    // initialize on enterframe
    //var snapTextArray:Array = new Array();
    var allSWFLoaded:Boolean = false;

    var avoidJumpingMarker:int = 0;

    var mc:MovieClip  = new MovieClip();;
        //addChild(mc);
        //addChild(container); // just gotta add containes to stage?
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     // create a new instance of the Loader class

    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("tmp1.swf"); // in this case both SWFs are in the same folder 

    var bob:Boolean = false;    


    var captureButton:SimpleButton;

    var markUpButton:SimpleButton;

     // hack, just initialize once
    var dummySprite:Sprite  = new Sprite();

         //var scrollPane:ScrollPane = scrollPaneOnStage;
    var scrollPane:ScrollPane;

    var libMC:MovieClip;     

    var loader:Loader;   

    var fLoader:forcibleLoader;
    var queue:LoaderMax;
    var markUpQueue:LoaderMax;



    var loaderArray:Array;
    var mcArray:Array;
    var mcArrayTest:Array = new Array();
    //
    var offSetArray:Array;
    var currentClip:int;

    var snapText:TextSnapshot;

    var snapTextArrayOffset:Array = new Array();


    var inter:int = 0;
    var noPages:int = 0;
    var pagesLoaded = 0;
    var justAMovieClip:MovieClip;

    // renanme this as well!
    public function expViewer10() {

        // wait till this class has been added to the stage!
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, attachButtonsNStuff);


        // dont use this, button should be there already
        //addChild(nextPageButton); 
        //attachButtonsNStuff();




    }

    private function attachButtonsNStuff(evt:Event):void {

        //scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        //addChild(scrollPane);
        // constructor code



        queue = new LoaderMax({name:"mainQueue", onProgress:progressHandler, onComplete:checkHandler, onError:onError});


        //this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        //MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1);


        mc.gotoAndStop(1);
        loadPages();


    }

    private function progressHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        //trace("progress: " + event.target.progress);
    }

    private function onError(event:LoaderEvent) {
        // trace("error occured with " + event.target + ": " + event.text);


    }

    private function checkHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {



            displayPages();




            MovieClip(root).addChild(mc);

            //mcArray[0].textSnapshot.setSelected( 4, 300, true );
            //queue.getContent( ("tmp1") ).rawContent.textSnapshot.setSelected( 4, 300, true );
        setTimeout ( function ( libMC:MovieClip ) : void {
                    try {
                     libMC.textSnapshot.setSelectColor( 0xFF0000 );
                     libMC.textSnapshot.setSelected( 100, 200, true ); 
                    } catch (error:Error) {
                        trace(error.message);

                    } finally {
                        trace("tada");

                    }
                     }, 
                 5000, 
                 mcArray[0]
               );

    }




    private function loadPages():void {

        try{

            noPages = 12;

            for (var i:int = 0 ; i < noPages ; i++){

                queue.append( new SWFLoader("tmp"+(i+1)+".swf", {name:"tmp"+(i+1), container:mc, estimatedBytes:70000, autoPlay:false, autoDispose:false}) );

            }
            queue.load(); 

        } catch (error:Error) {
             // statements
             //ExternalInterface.call("window.alert(\"load err: "+error.message+"\")");
        } finally {
             // statements
        }

    }


    private function displayPages():void {

            //trace('1');

            mcArray = new Array();

            offSetArray = new Array();

            var fromTop:Number = 0;

            var totalChars:int = 0;

            //ExternalInterface.call("window.alert(\"length err: "+loaderArray.length.toString()+"\")");

            for (var i:int=0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {

                //var tempmc:MovieClip =
                //justAMovieClip  = MovieClip(queue.getContent( ("tmp"+(i+1)) ).rawContent);

                mcArray[i] = queue.getContent( ("tmp"+(i+1)) ).rawContent;

                var rect:Rectangle = mcArray[i].getRect(this);

                //trace(inter++);

                //mc.addChild(mcArray[i]);

                mcArray[i].gotoAndStop(1);

                mc.getChildAt(i).y = fromTop;

                offSetArray.push(fromTop);

                fromTop += rect.height + 10; // margin - put on top


                totalChars += mcArray[i].textSnapshot.charCount;
                //ExternalInterface.call("window.alert(\"tot chars: "+totalChars+"\")");
                snapTextArrayOffset.push(totalChars);



            }




    }




}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should `gotoAndStop` the MovieClip *before* you set the color, otherwise the first keyframe might reset the text. Also, try using `gotoAndStop(1);`. The 0 frame does not exist on MovieClips.

**EDIT**

I remembered that some components might have a somewhat delayed initiation routine.  Try this:

```
function checkHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
    try {
        libMC = LoaderMax.getContent("childClip").rawContent as MovieClip;
        scrollPane.source = libMC;
        libMC.gotoAndStop(1); 
        setTimeout ( function ( libMC:MovieClip ) : void {
                         libMC.textSnapshot.setSelectColor( 0xFF0000 );
                         libMC.textSnapshot.setSelected( 100, 200, true ); 
                         }, 
                     100, 
                     libMC
                   );
        } catch (error:Error) {
            // statements
            ExternalInterface.call("window.alert(\"error: "+error.message+"\")");
        } finally {
            // statements
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: changing to gotoAndStop(1) unfortunately didnt resolve the issue - and in my current version it's already set before setting the color. dang

Comment: How about the root clip? There's another `gotoAndStop(0)` there.  Also, what's happening in `onEnterFrame`?

Comment: I've changed that one as well and still no difference. onEnterFrame currently doesnt do anything

Comment: thanks for sticking with me weltraumpirat. I tried your solution and the effect is zero aka its not possible to select text after a few ms (however no error gets thrown when doing so). my guess is that somewhere the content of the loadermax gets lost, even though it shouldnt. please check the full src above

Comment: Ok, I've tried a few things myself, and searched a couple of internet sources...  There was no way I could get the selection to show up, even when doing it without all the loader stuff. The TextSnapShot class in AS3 seems to be either broken, or buggy, or at least the documentation is horrible.  Can you use dynamic TextFields instead?

Comment: no, unfortunately I cant. the loaded swfs get created with swftools (from pdfs). the only thing that comes to my mind now, is creating my own highlighting class... because hitTestTextNearPos and gettext actually work...